# Firebase Value and ChildAdded (further explanation needed)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've read the Firebase documentation over and over and again and just need some clarification. This isn't regarding my specific code as much as my understanding of Firebase in general.

I know that `.Value` retrieves all the data each time its called and continues to monitor the database for changes. And `.ChildAdded` looks for changes in the children of the reference. Does `.ChildAdded` also retrieve all of the values initially? Should I be implementing both `.Value` and `.ChildAdded` for the same path? If not, when I try just doing `.ChildAdded`, nothing shows up but when I run `.Value`, all of my items show up like they are supposed to. What I don't want is for every value to be re-fetched from the database each time a single value is changed or added because that would seemingly cause some bandwidth issues later when I have thousands of items to fetch. Would be best workflow be to create a .Value function (`getAllItems()`) with ObserveSingleEventOfType so it only calls it once and then have a duplicate function (`getNewItems()`) except with `.ChildAdded` and observeEventOfType?

Answer (score 3):

if you have this node

```
 node:{
   data1:"data",
   data2:{
     subdata1:1,
     subdata2:2
   }
 }
```

`Value` with `observeEventOfType` will be called the first time + every time something inside `"node"` changes , `Value` with `observeSingleEventOfType` will be called only once

`Child_Added` with observeEventOfType will be called twice [`"data1"`(it will contain the string "data" and `"data2"`(it will contain an object with the childs `"subdata1"` and `"subdata2`"]

`Child_Changed` with `observeEventOfType` will be called every time `"data1"` or `"data2"` changed (an event in `"data2"` will be called every time `"subdata1"` or `"subdata2"` change, or if you insert a `"subdata3"`)

This can be used in combination but it depends in each scenario...

FOR THE EVENT TYPE:

usually when you are pointing at a final node like `"data1"` you use `Value` and when you are in a node that has a list of similar nodes like `"data2"` you use a combination of `child_added`, `child_changed` and `child_removed`

FOR THE OBSERVER TYPE:

it's straightforward if you want to get the value at a specific moment; you use the "single event observer". If you want to keep an eye of the value over time you use "event observer"

Comment: Makes sense. If my structure is like data2, why would .ChildAdded not work to fetch all of the values in the node initially (and continue to monitor for additions) but .Value works?

Comment: If your structure is like data2 child added will be called two times,1) the callback snapshot.key will be subdata1 and the value will be 1;  2) the callback snapshot.key will be subdata2 and the value will be 2.

Comment: It gets called this way to avoid  sending all the data over the network all the time,  it sends only the new data  as child_changed sends only the data that  changed